How can Venezuela technically suffer a power outage in all its states at the same time?
I have no knowledge in electricity, but I'm wondering how, technically, it was possible that Venezuela suffered a country wide power outage. All its states were affected, for a very long time.
What can stop functioning so direly that quite no electricity can reach anything?
I'm not interested in political reasons of that outage, only how so much electricity can stop being produced and delivered so definitively.
What things concretely might have happened that made its production or delivery stop.


What can stop functioning so direly that quite no electricity can reach anything?

Circuit breakers tripping.
Nationwide electricity systems tend to be arranged as complex grids of high voltage lines.  Major towns and cities will have multiple lines feeding them.  Normally, this works well, and a single failure can be handled by redirecting power.  But sometimes, that doesn't work.
Maybe there's an extreme weather event.  There's a storm, or it's very hot or cold.  Demand is higher than usual, for heating or air conditioning.
Then a major power station suffers a complete failure and goes offline.
This throws more load onto the surrounding network.  Soon, a line is overloaded and a circuit breaker trips.  This throws more load onto the remaining network, and another circuit breaker trips.  And another one, and another...
Before you know it, there's a cascading failure spereading across the country's grid.  If you're quick enough, you can stop it by shutting off the entire region that's affected.  If not, the entire grid goes down.
At that point, you need to initiate a "black start".  Which is difficult and takes time.  Every generator on the grid has to be synchronized.  So you start from one generator feeding only the local area.  Then add the remaining generators one at a time, bringing up a bit of the grid each time.

The List of major power outages Wikipedia page can be a starting point for finding possible technical causes of country wide power outages.
The linked 2019 Argentina, Paraguay and Uruguay blackout has the following which describes how a single fault led to a succession of automatic disconnections:

The blackout is believed to have been caused by an operational misbehavior from Transener, a transmission lines operator in Argentina. A 500 kV line running from Colonia Elía to Campana, crossing the Paraná Guazú river, was down on undergoing maintenance to repair the tower number 412, whose base had been suffering from erosion by the river. The company made a bypass for this tasks, using a nearby overhead line, but missed to reflect that network grid change in the Automatic Generation Shutdown system (in spanish: DAG), which is designed to alert energy generators of network changes that would require a lower of energy generation. This caused, after a short circuit which lowered demand, an excess of power generation in the grid, a lack of synchronization of power plants, loss of balance, and a low frequency in the network.
In about 30 seconds, a succession of automatic disconnections from the grid caused a blackout that came to affect 50 million users in the continent.

